# mix.scripts is not working (webpack.mix.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-mix

i have the following webpack.mix.js:

```
const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');
mix.scripts([
    'resources/assets/js/app.js',
    'resources/assets/js/definers.js',
    'resources/assets/js/tab_system.js',
    'resources/assets/js/searchbox.js',
    'node_modules/angular/angular.js',
], 'public/js/app.js', 'public/js');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/afegir_caracteristica_visuals.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/assets/js/afegir_categoria_visuals.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/assets/js/afegir_localitat_visuals.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/assets/js/afegir_tipo_visuals.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/assets/js/afegir_transaccio_visuals.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/assets/js/eliminar_element.js', 'public/js');

mix.styles([
    'resources/assets/css/tab_system.css',
    'resources/assets/sass/app.scss',
], 'public/css/app.css');
```

and when i run `npm run dev` i get this error:
[error in the cmd with the homestead ssh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V05uq.png)

Comment: before `npm run dev` did you execute `npm install`?

Comment: yes I did and nothing changed, I run npm install vanilla-js too in the project and nothing, same error.

Comment: Do you have a `node_modules/laravel-mix` directory ?

Comment: I do, in fact the other functions of laravel-mix work like a charm, but mix.scripts and mix.styles doesn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue, you should try to use mix.combine instead of mix.scripts.
So the first part of your script should become:

```
mix.combine([
    'resources/assets/js/app.js',
    'resources/assets/js/definers.js',
    'resources/assets/js/tab_system.js',
    'resources/assets/js/searchbox.js',
    'node_modules/angular/angular.js',
], 'public/js/app.js', 'public/js');
```

I found the solution here: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/blob/master/docs/concatenation-and-minification.md

Comment: You don't need the third param but everything else is perfect, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 3):

Well that might be a bit old topic but I was looking for solution on my own so:

```
npm update laravel-mix
```

and

```
npm install cross-env
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem
use

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
```