# Laravel javascript in file doesn't work, but does work if included through CDN

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-mix

This works:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var textWrapper = document.querySelector('.ml6 .letters');
textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/\S/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");

anime.timeline({loop: false})
    .add({
    targets: '.ml6 .letter',
    translateY: ["1.1em", 0],
    translateZ: 0,
    duration: 750,
    delay: (el, i) => 50 * i
});
</script>
```

But if I include the exact JS from the CDN in `libraries.js` as shown below, I get `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: anime`.

```
<script src="{{ mix('/js/libraries.js') }}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var textWrapper = document.querySelector('.ml6 .letters');
textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/\S/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");

anime.timeline({loop: false})
    .add({
    targets: '.ml6 .letter',
    translateY: ["1.1em", 0],
    translateZ: 0,
    duration: 750,
    delay: (el, i) => 50 * i
});
</script>
```

I checked and mix is compiling as it should, the JS is included in `libraries.js`.

It's the exact same script, included in the exact same location so I'm puzzled as to why this is not working. The only thing I can think of is that `libraries.js` is loaded *after* the script is ran. Is that the case? If so: how do I solve this?

I'm running into this issue more often. I would like to use `mix()` instead of `asset()`.
The above is about 1 library, but I would prefer to include all of most of the libraries I use in the one file `libraries.js`, but today I'm loading most of them through CDNs because of the issue described above.

Comment: Have you tried to add these lines on top of file ? `<script src="{{ mix('/js/libraries.js') }}"></script>
`

Comment: I don't want to move this file to my `<head>` if that is what you mean?

Comment: Because `libraries.js` might load after your js code loads. So that's why this issue persists. Check Your console.

Comment: The console only shows `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: anime`. If what you're saying is true, then how do I control when certain things load? Because now it's more of a gamble what comes first so it's hard to control what's loaded and when. I've just updated the question with the fact that even if I initiate the library *after* the library within the same file it still doesn't work.

Comment: Just as a test can you copy code from `libraries.js` in you code and try if its working.

Comment: Ok. Let me try the code and will tell You if I'm also facing the issue .

Comment: Can you show your mix.scripts? I had a similar issue, maybe try `mix.scripts()` or [`mix.combine()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42649614/4705339)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a file `resources/js/libraries.js` with a bunch of `require();` to import `npm` packages and another JS file to import custom code? Well I would like to suggest something:

You don't have to make a separate JS file for them, webpack can extract them automatically like:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .extract([
        'bootstrap', 
        'popper.js',
        'lodash',
        'axios',
        'jquery',
        'vue',
    ]);

mix.version();
```

Then you put this at the bottom of your layout:

```
<script src="{{ mix('js/manifest.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ mix('js/vendor.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
@stack('scripts')
```

`vendor.js` is basically your `libraries.js` and `app.js` is your custom code.

When you `mix.version()`: If your custom code changes and you `npm run prod`, only `app.js` will change (which is a small JS file) and the `vendor.js` (which is a big file) will stay exactly the same. This is a huge advantage as old users will only have to load the small `app.js` and the `vendor.js` will still be cached, making the loading faster.

---

**But to answer your question**, it's not picking up the variable name `anime`, so import it like this in your JS file to be recognized:

```
window.anime = require('animejs');
```

Comment: Thank you! The line `window.anime = require('animejs');` was indeed what I needed.

Comment: Glad it works :) You can mark it as the correct answer to avoid more answers :P

Comment: Whoops, forgot that, done now. To the first point in your answer, I can actually add another line like this `mix.js('resources/js/libraries.js', 'public/js')` and import all the libraries in that file to separate libraries and app javascript. That’s how this question came to he, and I’m very happy that I can now finally use this setup :-)

Comment: Hehe okay cool! To each their own :P glad you can move on now ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try `npm run watch` and then try again.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add this, but I have `npm run watch` compiling on every save, and I can see that the library is included in the `libraries.js` file but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you .

1. I have stored the give js file as `.min.js` format .
2. Instead of using `mix` ,
    I have used `asset` to get the js file .

```
<script src = "{{asset('js/anime.min.js')}}" type ="text/javascript"> </script>
```

Please check this. And I didn't find any issue on this .

Here is the complete code Which I have tried :

```
<script src = "{{asset('js/anime.min.js')}}" type ="text/javascript">
</script>
  <script>
  var textWrapper = document.querySelector('.ml6 .letters');
textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/\S/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");

anime.timeline({loop: false})
    .add({
    targets: '.ml6 .letter',
    translateY: ["1.1em", 0],
    translateZ: 0,
    duration: 750,
    delay: (el, i) => 50 * i
}).add({
    targets: '.ml6',
    opacity: 0,
    duration: 1000,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    delay: 1000
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I would still like to use mix as this is how I would compile all my assets for both my local and production environment. After your answer I'm even more puzzled as to why it doesn't work. If using `asset()` include the JS file works but `mix()` doesn't while the rest is the same, then why is that?

Comment: @eskimo For using mix you need to `compile `the `js code `into `mix code`.. For more,  https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mix

Comment: Yep I know. It's compiling perfectly fine. The JS code from `anime.min.js` is in the file `libraries.js`. So mix and compiling is working. It's just that as described in my question: if I load `anime.min.js` separately through the CDN it works, if I include it in the `libraries.js` file it doesn't. I still don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

try wrapping your inline js with :

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){ // here });
```